# "Missing required parameter 'client_id'" Error

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-google-login

I'm trying to let users authenticate using Google, but I get this error (shown in the image below)
[image]

The dependencies I'm using for google authentication are:

- "react-google-login": "^5.2.2" (for the frontend)
- "google-auth-library": "^8.2.0" (for the API)
- "react": "^18.1.0" (The version I'm on)

**Login Page Code:**

```
import { useEffect, useContext, useRef } from "react";
import { Context } from "../../context/Context";
import axios from "axios";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { GoogleLogin } from "react-google-login";
import { googleLoginCall } from "./googleLogin";

export default function Register() {
  const userRef = useRef();
  const passwordRef = useRef();
  const { dispatch, isFetching } = useContext(Context);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    //NORMAL LOGIN CODE
  };

  // GOOGLE LOGIN
  const handleLogin = async (googleData) => {
    const res = await fetch('/auth/google-login', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        token: googleData.tokenId,
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    googleLoginCall(data.user, dispatch);
    console.log(data.user);
  };

  return (
    <div className="login">
      <Box>
      <Stack>
        <Box>
          <Stack>

      {/* LOGIN FORM */}
      <form className="loginForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Stack>
          
          <Typography>
          Login to
          </Typography>

          {/* HERE IS THE PROBLEM */}
          <GoogleLogin
          clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
            buttonText="Log in with Google"
            onSuccess={handleLogin}
            onFailure={handleLogin}
            cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
          />

          <Divider style={{width:'100%'}}>
            Or
            </Divider>

            {/* Username or Email Address */}
              {/* NORMAL LOGIN USERNAME OR EMAIL INPUT */}

          {/* Password */}
            {/* NORMAL LOGIN PASSWORD INPUT */}
        </Stack>
      </form>

      {/* LOGIN FORM ENDS */}

          </Stack>
          </Box>

      </Stack>
      </Box>

      </div>
  )
}
```

I tried changing `clientId` to `client_id` but still didn't work.

Comment: Have you checked that `process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID` is correctly defined?

Comment: Even if I don't use .env and write the client id itself it still the same.

Comment: Ok cool; was just going for the obvious answer first :-)

Comment: after searching, it seems like react-google-login is not working anymore so i'm looking for alternatives now, thank you anyways.